# Django Twitter OAuth authentication

Tags: python, django, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to implement a Twitter authentication via OAuth on my Django application, but I'm stuck at this error after receiving the Twitter callback:

```
Traceback:

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/flavioramos/projects/sobo/sobo/../sobo/views.py" in twitter_authenticated
  105.     auth_login(request, user)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  71.     user.save()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in save
  430.         raise NotImplementedError

Exception Type: NotImplementedError at /login/authenticated
Exception Value:
```

My login/authenticated view is the following:

```
def twitter_authenticated(request):
    token = oauth.Token(request.session['request_token']['oauth_token'],
        request.session['request_token']['oauth_token_secret'])
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

    resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "GET")
    if resp['status'] != '200':
        print content
        raise Exception("Invalid response from Twitter.")

    access_token = dict(cgi.parse_qsl(content))

    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=access_token['screen_name'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User.objects.create_user(access_token['screen_name'],
            '%s@twitter.com' % access_token['screen_name'],
            access_token['oauth_token_secret'])

        profile = Profile()
        profile.user = user
        profile.oauth_token = access_token['oauth_token']
        profile.oauth_secret = access_token['oauth_token_secret']
        profile.save()


    user = authenticate(username=access_token['screen_name'],password=access_token['oauth_token_secret'])

    auth_login(request, user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

This code is from a python-oauth2 sample application.

Do I have to write my own authentication backend for this?

I'm new at Django and any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue. Seems that the libs used by oauthtwitter have changed. To patch your local version do the following:

in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/oauth_python_twitter-1.0-py2.6.egg/oauthtwitter.py
```

find line 37 and change it from:

```
Api.__init__(self, access_token.key, access_token.secret)
```

to:

```
Api.__init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token.key, access_token.secret)
```

Now all the required variables are passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but I think

*auth_login(request, user)*

Should be: *login(request, user)*

(and ofcourse this *login* should be imported from *django.contib.auth* on top of your login/authenticated view )